# Get everything between strings and replace with something else

Tags: php

I am trying to get everything between the {code} tags from the $html string.

So far I have written this but this doesn't work as expected, only replacing the first {code}

Also I would like this to work for many code tags, but haven't gotten this far yet.

```
<?php    

$html = <<< EOT
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>{code}My test code 1{/code}</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
EOT;

$startPos = strpos($html, '{code}');
$endPos = strpos($html, '{/code}');
if($startPos !== false && $endPos !== false){
    $startPos += 6; # strlen('{code}')
    $endPos += 7; # strlen('{/code}')

    // get code
    $code = substr($html, $startPos, $endPos);

    // remove all code apart from start {code}
    $html = substr($html, $startPos-6, $endPos);

    // replace new code
    $new_code = 'test';
    $html = str_replace('{code}', $new_code, $html);
}

echo $html;
```

**Result**: - http://codepad.viper-7.com/T9sbbN

> testMy test code 1{/code}
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

**Expected Result**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>
> test
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Arian just added this

Comment: if there are multiple `{code}addasdf{/code}` tags do you want all of them to be replaced with `$new_Code`?

Comment: As an example that it fine yes, its doing database lookup in real application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for one {code}.

```
<?php

$html = <<< EOT
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>{code}My test code 1{/code}</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 
EOT;

$startPos = strpos($html, '{code}');
$endPos = strpos($html, '{/code}');

if($startPos !== false && $endPos !== false){
    $startPos += 6; # strlen('{code}')


    // get code
    $code = substr($html, $startPos, $endPos-$startPos);


    // replace new code
    $new_code = 'test';
    $html = str_replace('{code}'.$code.'{/code}', $new_code, $html);
}

echo $html;
```

Multiple could look like this:

```
<?php

$html = <<< EOT
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>{code}My test code 1{/code}</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.{code}hi{/code}</p> 
EOT;

$html = test($html);

echo $html;

function test($html){
    do{
        $startPos = strpos($html, '{code}');
        $endPos = strpos($html, '{/code}');

        if($startPos !== false && $endPos !== false){
            $startPos += 6; # strlen('{code}')

            // get code
            $code = substr($html, $startPos, $endPos-$startPos);

            // replace new code
            $new_code = 'test';
            $html = str_replace('{code}'.$code.'{/code}', $new_code, $html);
        }

    }while($startPos !== false && $endPos !== false);


    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly, am I correct in thinking that this is slightly better than doing a big string replace? `$html = substr($html, 0, $startPos-6) . $new_code . substr($html, $endPos+7);`

Comment: @JohnMagnolia Yes it gives you the ability to edit functionality by doing it in a function... also note, this code doesn't account for a nested situation where `{code}This is {code}here{/code} and here{/code}`

Comment: Wow now that would be getting complex, thankfully it doesn't need that at this stage yet.

Answer (score 1):

regexp exsample

```
$html = preg_replace('/{code}.*{\/code}/', 'test', $html);
```

with your code: [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/or2X0q)

check out cool reg exp builder:[regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#/%7Bcode%7D.%2a%7B%5C/code%7D/)

Comment: How can I break this down into getting the code first, so I can perform my logic, then replace it like you have here is perfect.

Comment: you can use limit, 4-th parameter into preg_replace [documentation](http://ua1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)